# EF Code Frirst: Before you update your database using Code First Migrations,

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I just updated `EntityFramework` from V6.0.2 to V6.1 and also to the latest `ASP.NET Identity`. After that I tried to create a migration file for limiting the length of the username which is now possible with the new version of `ASP.NET Identity Framework` released today.

This is the error message I got:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. This could have happened because the model
>   used by ASP.NET Identity Framework has changed or the model being used
>   in your application has changed. To resolve this issue, you need to
>   update your database. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301867).  Before
>   you update your database using Code First Migrations, please disable
>   the schema consistency check for ASP.NET Identity by setting
>   throwIfV1Schema = false in the constructor of your
>   ApplicationDbContext in your application.
>           `public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationServices", throwIfV1Schema:false)`

I'm especially interested in this line:

> Before you update your database using Code First Migrations, please
>   disable the schema consistency check for ASP.NET Identity by setting
>   throwIfV1Schema = false in the constructor of your
>   ApplicationDbContext in your application.

Why would I want to do that? And for how 'long'?

Also, I haven't changed anything in the model since before and after the update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it's a one time occurrence while you upgrade your database.

You can read more at the [.NET Web Development and Tools Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0/). And also see [Updating ASP.NET applications from ASP.NET Identity 1.0 to 2.0.0-alpha1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1/) linked from that blog post.

Comment: I did disable the schema consistency and did the migration. Then I turned it back on. So far it seems to work.

Answer (score 17):

Bool param throwIfV1Schema throws exception that asp.net Identity model has been changed (updated to new version 2).

Change your IdentityDbContext constructor for one time migration:

```
public YourDbContext() : base("YourConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema:false){}
```